# Identify only the text regions in an image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm developing a python script to identify text from images. So far I've been able to identify well separated text in the image.

working:

[image: working]

separated contours:

[image: separated contours]

But if there are objects around text region, it fails to identify.

failed:

[image: failed]

When an object's edge connects with a text edge it is identified as one contour.

connected contours:

[image: connected contours]

I want to detect only the edges of text regions.

Also I need a method to get a binarized image of the text region (white text in a black background) for the character segmentation step. Currently I'm using an inverting method based on the color of edge pixels but it doesn't work always

```
# read image
img_no = '197'
rgb = cv2.imread(img_no + '.jpg')
# cv2.imshow('original', rgb)

# convert image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# bilateral filter
blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 5, 75, 75)
# cv2.imshow('blur', blur)

# morphological gradient calculation
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
grad = cv2.morphologyEx(blur, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
# cv2.imshow('gradient', grad)

# binarization
_, bw = cv2.threshold(grad, 0.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('otsu', bw)

# closing
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (6, 1))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imshow('closed', closed)

black_bg = np.zeros_like(closed)
black_bg_copy = np.zeros_like(gray)

# finding contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

mask = np.zeros(closed.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

for idx in range(len(contours)):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[idx])
    mask[y:y + h, x:x + w] = 0
    area = cv2.contourArea(contours[idx])
    aspect_ratio = float(w) / h
    roi = closed[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    selected = gray.copy()[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, idx, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    r = float(cv2.countNonZero(mask[y:y + h, x:x + w])) / (w * h)

    # identify region of interest
    if r > 0.34 and 0.52 < aspect_ratio < 10 and area > 145.0:
        cv2.rectangle(rgb, (x, y), (x + w - 1, y + h - 1), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        black_bg[y:y + h, x:x + w] = roi
        _, bw_final = cv2.threshold(selected, 0.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
        print("top" + str(bw_final[0, 0]))
        print("bot" + str(bw_final[h - 1, w - 1]))
        #cv2.imshow('black', bw_final)
        if bw_final[0, 0] == 0 or bw_final[h - 1, w - 1] == 0:
            black_bg_copy[y:y + h, x:x + w] = bw_final
        else:
            inverted = cv2.bitwise_not(bw_final)
            black_bg_copy[y:y + h, x:x + w] = inverted

cv2.imshow('rectangles', rgb)
# cv2.imshow('result', black_bg)
cv2.imshow('output', black_bg_copy)
```

Comment: What's your actual question? Everyone trying to bypass capcha has a similar problem.

Comment: @MadPhysicist this for my final year project. I'm developing an application to identify text on video thumbnails. But when objects are around the text regions as shown in the 3rd image I can't identify the text alone. Background edges get in the way of text.